# Entry.notFound error when trying to update anything in admin panel

Tags: javascript, node.js, strapi

I've got a problem with updating anything in admin panel in Strapi. For example I've created a post for my blog in this panel, but when i try to udpade it, it's not working.
Im using heroku as a PaaS and mongo atlas as DB.
Ive got two environments for this blog, prod and staging (both working on heroku) and currently everything is working in my prod app but exactly the same code pushed to staging env is giving me this error visible in heroku logs during update:

```
2020-04-21T19:28:08.098766+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-21T19:28:08.098Z] error Error: 
entry.notFound
2020-04-21T19:28:08.098777+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.update (/app/node_modules/strapi- 
connector-mongoose/lib/queries.js:433:19)
2020-04-21T19:28:08.098779+00:00 app[web.1]: at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
2020-04-21T19:28:08.098780+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections 
(internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
2020-04-21T19:28:08.098781+00:00 app[web.1]: at async Object.update 
(/app/node_modules/strapi-plugin-users-permissions/controllers/User.js:232:18)
2020-04-21T19:28:08.098782+00:00 app[web.1]: at async module.exports 
(/app/node_modules/strapi-plugin-content-manager/config/policies/routing.js:35:9)
2020-04-21T19:28:08.098783+00:00 app[web.1]: at async module.exports 
(/app/node_modules/strapi-plugin-users-permissions/config/policies/permissions.js:40:14)
2020-04-21T19:28:08.098783+00:00 app[web.1]: at async /app/node_modules/strapi- 
utils/lib/policy.js:118:7
2020-04-21T19:28:08.098783+00:00 app[web.1]: at async evalmachine.<anonymous>:70:11
```

I am fighting with that since 3 hours and now I'm lack of new ideas what's going wrong.
Help needed!

Comment: It seems that whatever is querying MongoDB to update the object is unable to find it. It also seems like you are trying to search for it using the time code when it was created `2020-04-21T19:28:08.098Z`. Please confirm you are using the correct identifier, and provide more code so we can help you.

Comment: I have encountered the same issue, when I had a conflict with primary key in legacy database. In my case, database had "ID" column uppercase. MySQL is case insensitive for columns, but Strapi needed "id" in lowercase. I ended with renaming MySQL id columns to lowercase in all tables.
This isn't the case for Mongo, because it has "_id" column as a key, but I recommend you to check your database structure.